# Mongoose - Save function does nothing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm learning Mongoose, and I got a bug while saving a user. This is my `User Model` :

[image: User Model]

This is my `route` :

[image: Api Route - User Save]

The `MongoDB` connection is correct, I see it in the console, and `Postman` only shows a `Loading Page..`

I don't know why it is not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code as code block, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it.

My MongoDB Connection url was :

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/alexcaron
```

I've just updated it to

```
mongodb://localhost/alexcaron
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you explained, and without more logging data, using Mongoose 4.4.12, the word **new** maybe?

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/examples/schema/schema.js#L14

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = require('./models/users_model');
```

For using user:

```
var user = new User({
    courriel: "test1",
    password: "test2"
});
```

Comment: Question : Does my collection need to be created ?

Comment: Mongoose won't create the User collection until the first document of that model is saved. User.create({"password": "test2", "courriel": "test1"}, function(err, doc) {
    // The User collection is created
});

Comment: Ok, thanks. I dont know how to have more logging data, sorry.

Comment: The .save() is never fired.

Comment: Ah! I found that mongoose can't open a connection.